# Can "treat" be used as a generic term for junk food, drinks or sweets?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the shortest word that can capture the idea of guilty pleasure, limited to the products we consume (it doesn't have to be extended to activities).

For example, you would say "no xxx for me today" when you resist an impulse or desire for products like junk food, drinks, sweets, or maybe even cigarettes.

Ideally, this would include any activity involving the consumption of a product that gives you pleasure but that you consider bad for some personal reason (health, environment, finances...).

The best I could come up with is "treat".

These things may be too ordinary to be considered treats, but I think that's only because they've become very affordable in recent years. You still "treat yourself" a little bit when you give yourself one, and part of the guilt comes from the fact that you give yourself one without deserving it. Or is it just my perception?

Comment: I'd say that _treat_ works as well as any other word.

Comment: I’m not giving in to temptation today!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [vice](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/vice)

> A vice is a habit that is regarded as a weakness in someone's character, but not usually as a serious fault.

Or while longer, [indulgence](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/indulgence) can be similar in meaning as well

> a pleasure, habit, etc, indulged in; extravagance
> fur coats are an indulgence

Comment: Isn't vice a bit too judgmental?

Comment: Yes however the part of the question "that you consider bad for some personal reason" implies that you're already placing a judgement on it, thus allowing vice to work. Vice may imply something to be a little more habitual than you're asking for though in which case indulgence would seem appropriate (though probably longer than you'd like).

Answer (score 2):

I would use the slightly pompous [***gourmandise*** (Collins)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gourmandise):

> a love of and taste for good food

which would add a spicy little self-irony to the statement

> No ***gourmandise*** for me today!

or

> No ***gourmet food*** for me today!

Another word referring to `the activity involving the consumption of a product that gives you pleasure` would be:

> ***Fine-dining***

I agree that these words rather emphasise the rarity and exquisite quality of the food, but guilty pleasure goes with it and the word you gave, ***treat***, directed me this way.

PS: You do know that there is such a phrase as [***guilty pleasure foods***](https://www.eatthis.com/most-popular-guilty-pleasures/)? Chewing gum is on top of the list of the most unhealthy ones.

**Addition:** Just thought you might be able to use ***delicacy***, or even better the very simple and unpretentious ***goody*** that says it all:

> No ***goodies*** for me today!

Comment: Thanks! It's too long, but definitely a word I will use for related content.

Comment: Also, your link to the "guilty pleasure foods" article made me smile because I opened it a couple of days ago. We can say we're on the same page.

Comment: Mm, I visited the site only for linguistic reasons :) !

Comment: The question specifically asked for a term for **junk** food, while this answer is mostly about the opposite of junk food.